# How to install a particular package through package.json in node directory into a different directory?

Tags: node.js, package.json

here is sample `package.json` file

```
dependencies {
       "inversify": "^5.0.1"
}
```

I would like to install the package into different directory `inversify_backup` under `node_modules` . Is there any option  to do it

Answer (score 0):

Is this your folder structure?

- node_modules

  - inversify_backup

Technically you could `cd node_modules/inversify_backup` then run `npm i <package-name>`.

Although your dependency install would be overwritten when running in production when the build job runs the `npm install` command.

I would recommend forking the inversify repository and just including it in your code if you need to make changes to the library.

Comment: yes I want to install `inversify` into `node_modules/inversify_backup`

Comment: I'm not really understanding why you want to do this. Are you trying to backup the library?

Comment: we have an inhouse lib as `inversify`, so we want the npm module to installed into a different folder.

Comment: `npm i inversify_backup@npm:inversify`